# Are there any famous English poems that every British-raised or American-raised person knows?

Tags: american-english, british-english, poetry, literature

In the Chinese language, there is a poem named Quiet Night Thoughts(Jing Ye Si) by Li Bai, which is known by everyone that is native to China (from little kids to very old people, even if they are illiterate). I'm wondering, in terms of poems, are there any counterparts in the English speaking world?

I asked a similar question on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-famous-English-poems-that-every-British-raised-or-American-raised-person-knows), but it didn't gather enough attention. I need to collect enough information to write an article on this topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about culture/poetry, not the use of English

Comment: Are you talking about knowing the names of poems or the ability to recite a poem by heart? You could argue that the American national anthem  is *known* but not every British born citizen will know the words. This is only an example, a song is not the same as a poem.

Comment: Mary had a little lamb, it's fleece was white as snow.  And everywhere that Mary went the lamb was sure to go.  It followed her to school one day, which was against the rules.  It made the children laugh and play, and so there was no school.

Comment: There are a multitude of poems about the lovely town of Nantucket, Massachusetts and a variety of its fine residents, but I probably could not guarantee that more than half of the US population knows them and I definitely would not guarantee that any of them are famous.

Comment: There is certainly nothing comparable to 静夜思. Even foreigners in China quickly learn to recite 床前明月光，疑是地上霜，举头望明月 ，低头思故乡 (I learnt it in my second year), and it really _is_ ubiquitous, as well as being a classic that's well over a thousand years old. Nothing comparable exists in the English language, to my knowledge.

Comment: "Baa baa, black sheep, have you any wool?", "Ring around the rosie," and "London Bridge is falling down" are well-known children's poems/songs

Comment: @Fumble This is partly about culture, but it's also about an aspect of how the English language is used. Idioms are on-topic, and this poem is effectively an idiom in Chinese, it's that ingrained. To ask whether English has any similar pieces is on-topic here, I think. It's sort of the opposite point of entry to a “how well-established is _X_” question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You don't have to be able to recite it by heart. It's enough that you are aware the poem exists and people in the English speaking world can recognize it. It shouldn't be restricted to one certain country, but it should be universally recognized in the English speaking world. For the Chinese poem I cited in the question, you don't need to be born in China, Taiwan, Hong Kong, Singapore or Malaysia to be familiar with it.

Comment: @Janus: Well, I suppose the vast majority of Anglophones know *"Wherefore art thou, Romeo?"*. Which was written many centuries *after* Jing Ye Si, yet is obviously only very loosely connected to English as used today, so I question how much relevance *any* (earlier or later) suggestion here has to ELU as such.

Comment: @PapaPoule - And many of them should not be repeated in "polite company".

Comment: In America, I think the majority (perhaps not the totality) of English speakers would probably know the Cat in the Hat and/or Fox in Socks by [Seuss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Seuss). I'm not sure that's poetry. Maybe, Goodnight Moon?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I can certainly recite much of some Richard Scarry books.  Not so much Seuss, other than "Green Eggs and Ham".

Comment: @HotLicks It wasn't until I had children that I realized what a genius Seuss was.

Comment: Then it has to be nursery rhymes: Jack and Jill; London Bridge; Hokey Cokey; Georgie Porgie; Oranges & Lemons etc.. Then if it's anything grander it has to Shakespeare sonnet *Shall I compare thee to a summer's day? Thou art more lovely and more temperate:...*

Comment: As I'm slowly getting the gist of what you want, I'm thinking that some of the works of Shakespeare would best fit.  Most people in the US and UK have been exposed to a fair range of Shakespeare's work, and many have the nature of "meta idioms" in that reciting a few words will cause a mental association with a given scenario.

Comment: I'm thinking of "Alas, poor Yorick", "Out, out, damned spot", "Oh, Romeo", "Double double toil and trouble", etc.  Each brings forth an image to most people.

Comment: If it's Shakespeare, one obvious choice is Hamlet's soliloquy, starting: *"To be, or not to be: that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,
And by opposing end them? ..."* I expect most people in the English-speaking world will recognize this.

Comment: Maybe Auden's *Funeral Blues*, thanks to Four Weddings and a Funeral, or Lear's delightful nonsense poem *The Owl and the Pussycat*, or on a more serious note Blake's *The Tyger*. Tennyson's *The Charge of the Light Brigade* perhaps... its existence is well known but I am not sure how many people have ever read it! Soliloquys from Shakespeare's plays are not really poems... do they still count?

Comment: How about Carroll's *Jabberwocky*?

Comment: @RoaringFish: whether Shakespeare's soliloquies count depends on why the OP wants the answer, which he hasn't told us. And as to the question of whether they are poems? They are in iambic pentameter, so they have more structure than many modern poems, and they certainly are on a par with many poems in terms of metaphors and inventive use of language.

Comment: @PeterShor ~ I am not disputing the quality of Shakespeare's soliloquys, but they are very distinct from poems. The relevant distinction is that a poem is a self-contained structure while a soliloquy needs the context of the play in which it appears. I am familiar with the structuralist arguments that poems rely on pre-existing knowledge which blurs the notion of 'the beginning', but the text itself is still self-contained.

Comment: @Roaring Fish: I totally agree with you. But whether or not this is relevant depends on why the OP wants the answer.

Comment: @PeterShor Let me put it this way: suppose a group of people whose mother tongue is English get together. We don't know where they come from, what their education backgrounds are, or how old they are. Then one person opens a conversation with such a poem that the majority of the people there have varying degrees of knowledge about it. They don't have to be able to recite part of the poem. It's enough that each one of them shares some knowledge about the poem. To me, such a poem can be regarded as a cultural identifier.

Comment: I think that a number of well-known quotations, especially those by Shakespeare, would fit your requirements, even though they are not technically "poems".

Comment: ***Three Rings for the Elven-kings under the sky, / 
Seven for the Dwarf-lords in their halls of stone, / 
Nine for Mortal Men doomed to die, / 
 One for the Dark Lord on his dark throne / 
 In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie. //
One Ring to rule them all, / One Ring to find them, / 
One Ring to bring them all / And in the darkness bind them // 
 In the Land of Mordor where the Shadows lie.***

Comment: *The woods are lovely, dark, and deep, /
But I have promises to keep, /
And miles to go before I sleep, /
**And miles to go before I sleep.***

Comment: *What a piece of work is a man, how noble in reason, how
 infinite in faculties, in form and moving how express and /
 admirable, in action how like an angel, in apprehension how like /
 a god! the beauty of the world, the paragon of animals—and yet, /
 to me, what is this quintessence of dust? Man delights not me— /
 nor woman neither, though by your smiling you seem to say so.*

Comment: *To-morrow, and to-morrow, and to-morrow, /
 Creeps in this petty pace from day to day,/
 To the last syllable of recorded time; /
 And all our yesterdays have lighted fools /
 The way to dusty death. Out, out, brief candle! /
 Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player, /
 That struts and frets his hour upon the stage, /
 And then is heard no more. It is **a tale / 
 Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury, / 
 Signifying nothing.***

Comment: There really are dozens, possibly hundreds of these. Yes, some of them are like “Hey diddle diddle the cat and the fiddle the cow  jumps over the moon” but many others are deeper shared cultural touchstones, like “England’s green and pleasant land” or “To sail beyond the sunset, and the baths / 
Of all the western stars, until I die.” or “Half a league, half a league, /
 Half a league onward, /
All in the valley of Death /
 Rode the six hundred.” or “Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary”. Not everyone will know all of them, but most educated people will.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Et tu, Brute?* Unfortunately, the number of people who think *wherefore* means *where* in the Juliet quotation instead of *why* is simply appalling, so they fail to understand that quote. Give them something simpler, like Antoni’s “Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears; I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him.”

Comment: Wordsworth's _Daffodils_ - "I wandered, lonely as a cloud..." used to be the classic 'poem that every schoolchild knows' in England, but I don't know if that's still the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a list of poems that most speakers of American English know very well, primarily because of their historic, cultural, **and** **linguistic** (i.e. many well-known expressions in common use today originated therefrom) importance:

“[No Man is an Island](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/no-man-is-an-island/),” which is the penultimate paragraph of “Meditation #17”/*Meditation XVII from Devotions upon Emergent Occasions* (1623-24) by John Donne (1572-1631), who was an English poet and a cleric in the Church of England;

*[Paul Revere's Ride](http://poetry.eserver.org/paul-revere.html)* (1860) by Henry Wadsworth Longfellow (1807-1882), who was an American poet;

*[Casey at the Bat: A Ballad of the Republic Sung in the Year 1888](http://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/casey-bat)* (1888) by Ernest Lawrence Thayer under the pen name “Phin” (1863 – 1940), who was an American writer and poet;

*[I’m nobody! Who are you?](http://www.poetrysoup.com/famous/poem/41/Im_nobody_Who_are_you)* (1891) by Emily Elizabeth Dickinson (1830 – 1886), who was an American poet;

*[In Flanders Fields](http://www.arlingtoncemetery.net/flanders.htm)* (1915) by Lieutenant Colonel John McCrae, MD (November 30, 1872 – January 28, 1918), a Canadian poet, physician, author, artist, and soldier during World War I, who died of pneumonia near the end of that war;

and

[*Harlem* aka *A Dream Deferred*](http://genius.com/Langston-hughes-harlem-what-happens-to-a-dream-deferred-annotated) from *Montage of a Dream Deferred* (1951) by James Mercer Langston Hughes (February 1, 1902 – May 22, 1967) who was an American poet, social activist, novelist, playwright, and columnist.

Comment: A couple of those I'm not at all familiar with, and for none of them could I quote much more than the title.  And I regard myself as a reasonably literate native-born US citizen.

Comment: *Paul Revere's Ride*, *Casey at the Bat*, and probably anything by Langston Hughes, are going to be completely unknown outside of the U.S. But maybe the OP shouldn't be asking for poems that are well-known across the entire English-speaking world.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misread the question. I read the "or" in the "question heading" to mean that the OP is wondering if such poems exist on either side of the Atlantic and that answers could/would be different, depending on which side of it they came from. @PeterShor